# Trying to Plot a function and not getting an output

Tags: plotting

I've been using this to plot the function. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Plot[1/(-1+(e^CubeRoot[x]),{x,0,1}]
```

Comment: The natural log base is E, not e.

Comment: I fixed that and now all I get is a black bracket with no output @DavidKeith

Comment: I’m away from my computer so I can’t run your code. But it also appears your parentheses are not balanced.

Comment: @KateC, try this input: `Plot[1/(-1 + E^CubeRoot[x]), {x, 0, 1}]`.